# Closing window from another window

Tags: javascript

There are two child windows B and C. And the parent window is A. I want to close the C window when a user clicks a button in B.

window.opener() gives a reference to the parent object. For testing purposes lets assume C window name is also "name". Then below code invoked from B should close  C window.

But it doesn't work.

```
  var windowObjectReference = window.opener.open("www.google.com" , "name");
  windowObjectReference.close();
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the parentwindow has a reference to the child windows, just use the parent window to set the handler of the button in the B child window.
Something like:

```
var windowB = window.open( ... ),
    windowC = .... ,
    buttonB = windowB.document.querySelector(...yourButtonReference...);
buttonB.onclick = function() {
    windowC.close();
    window.open('http://www.google.com');
}
```

If you don't want to close the C window, you could try replacing the window.location of the C window with google.
Your parent window has all the references, so it's easier to have the parent window do all the opening/closing instead of having the child windows try to access their siblings.